# delayed_paperclip and load balancer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, delayed-job

It seems paperclip and/or delayed_paperclip saves a temporary file on local web server fs before upload it to S3 or Rackspace Cloud File (i'm using fog.io).

If you have a worker for delayed_job on a separated server, this worker won't be able to see this tmp file on the web sever.

Or you could have one worker in each web server, but then worker1 on webserver1 can't see files on webserver2. You would need a queue/server affinity, right?

So the question is: how should I use delayed_paperclip with load balancer?

Thank you!

Comment: Got any update on this question, asker?

Comment: I still don't know the answer but using it on Heroku with 10 dynos worked fine for me. It seems (I'm not sure about that) it saves the image data on DB, not on the local server.